# IOS (Objective C) and Bing Translation API - Encoding Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, url-encoding, bing-api

I am running into URL encoding issue while connecting to Microsoft translation api from the objective c code.

The `<Enter> (\n)` are not getting encoded properly. Below is my code:

This is how I encode the string in IOS code before hitting http://api.microsofttranslator.com

```
NSString *urlEncodedString = [mytext stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The response from the bing translation is encoded back as

```
NSString *response_txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

The challenge that I am facing is, if there are enters in myText, the the translated text shows it as \u000a. For e.g.

If the input is:

```
 This is line 1.
 <enter>
 This is line 2.
```

The Translated Text is

```
This is line 1.\u000aThis is line 2.
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that `'\u000a'` is the code for `newline`? Where is is shown that way? Using `NSLog()`?

Comment: yes, it is a code for new line. The thing is, 'NSString *response_txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ; ' it is not replacing the 'u000a' with enter / new line. In the textbox, it is shown as 'u000a'

Comment: i think, i need to use stringByRemovingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding or something similar. Let me try it.

Comment: No Luck. :(. It is not working.

Comment: Wow, the translator really delivers `'\u000a'` as clear text? What is the format of it? You have to sent it to a parser. Is it JSON? (I do not know MS Translator.)

Comment: Yes, you need something like that, but percent encodings are the "%" encodings you see in an URL: Something different. I do not remember that there is a method that interpretes code escapes. Hmm, maybe you have to do it your own.

Comment: Yes, the api returns 'uoooa'. It seems there is an issue with Ios method, the url encoding is not working the way it should be.

Comment: Can you print out the url and add the result to your Q, please.

Comment: Here is the query url(notice enter / newline has been replaced with %0A before hitting the api)

https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?&text=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A%0A%0A&from=en&to=en

However, the result from the api is:

"1 2 3 4 5\u000a\u000a\u000a"

(notice that the %0A between 1 and 2 are replaced by spaces and the %0A in the end has been replaced by \u000a.

i have reached out to MSDN forum too. Not sure if it is an API issue.

Comment: Yes, looks linke you have to do it yourself. Can you do that or do you need help for it?

Comment: thanks, i have programmatically replaced the sequence.